# What is the benefit in getting the current time this way as opposed to using System.currentTimeInMillis()

Tags: java, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [System.currentTimeMillis() vs. new Date() vs. Calendar.getInstance().getTime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368094/system-currenttimemillis-vs-new-date-vs-calendar-getinstance-gettime)

I have just come across this in some legacy code:

```
GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()
```

This just seems like a very circuitous way of calling `System.currentTimeInMillis()`.

The server that this code runs on is probably running in a timezone other than UTC, but looking at the source of Date.getTime() everything will be GMT-based anyway (yes, I know that GMT doesn't precisely equal UTC).

Could there be a benefit I'm not aware of?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368094/system-currenttimemillis-vs-new-date-vs-calendar-getinstance-gettime

Comment: also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960082/is-calendar-getinstance-gettime-ever-going-to-give-me-a-different-answer-tha/11960343#11960343. Not sure but helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the links - I've voted to close my question - feel free to do the same!

Comment: I can't, more +101 to go to close. :)